# Reading from an input file C++, spliting by commas

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C++. I have an input file in the following format(it begins with a new empty line then bunch of strings(e.g. 117b,44b,...,197f,f) separated by commas which possibly can span over one line as you can see below then 2 numbers of threads (e.g. 10, 15) then some function calls):

"

117b,44b,19r,9b,6r,f,f,f,41b,21r,f,f,f,89r,72b,f,75r,f,f,96b,92r,f,f,101r,f,f,146b,133b,126r,f,f,145r,f,f,186b,185r,f,f,197f,f

Search threads: 10

Modify threads: 15

insert(150) || insert(25) || insert(163) || delete(25) || delete(6) || search(101) || search(163) || search(6)

"

I want to read the file and store the strings from 117b to f in an array of strings (or vector) so that the array looks like this = ["117b","44b","19r",...,"197f","f"]. Then I want to store the number of search thread in an int variable and the number of modify threads in another int variable.I tried to use the get line function to read from the file and splitting by commas but then the last element in the array won't just be "f" because it will continue reading since there's no comma at the end of the last "f". Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us your code, so we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a call to `getline()` along with a `std::stringstream` to stop once there are no more comma delimited tokens to read.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string str = "117b,44b,19r,9b,6r,f,f,f,41b,21r,f,f,f,89r,72b,f,75r,f,f,96b,92r,f,f,101r,f,f,146b,133b,126r,f,f,145r,f,f,186b,185r,f,f,197f,f";
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;

    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::string token; 
    while (getline(ss, token, ',')) //delimit on comma
        tokens.push_back(token);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
        std::cout << vect[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a predefined string though. the string above AND other information such as the number of search and modify threads are in an input file so this method will just take whatever is remaining after there are no more commas and add it to the last position of the array which we don't want because it needs to be "f", not "f Search Threads: 10 Modify Threads: 15  insert(150) || insert(25) || insert(163) || delete(25) || delete(6) || search(101) || search(163) || search(6)"

Comment: You can modify the code above to accomplish what you want provided the file always appears in that particular format (some number and character tokens delimited by commas followed by newline(s), search threads followed by newline(s), modify threads, etc. Knowing the actual format of the file will make it easier to answer your question (you only specify for the 117b,44b... part)

Comment: I have modified my post and included the actual format(please see above). The file   will exactly be the same as the content between the two quotation marks